# Patchwork Image interpolation

Tags: c++, 2d, interpolation, pixel, bicubic

I have manually generated a depthmap based on the vertices of my 3D-Model (no, i can't use the z-buffer in this case).

Unfortunately the depthmap is like a patchwork with many holes.
This is how it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHCKr.png

I somehow want to interpolate those missing holes, but i've never done something like this before and don't know how to approach this problem.

I was thinking about bicubic / bilinear interpolation. 
Is that what i need to apply to my problem?

If so, can you please explain to me how to undertake this approach? If that sort of interpolation is not the right one, how can i solve this hole problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you generated the depth map directly from the point cloud. One way of generating a dense depth map is to generate a mesh from the point cloud from which you can then easily obtain a dense depth map. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882993/mesh-generation-from-points-with-x-y-and-z-coordinates), for more information about mesh generation.